# Highlight selected button when clicked in Vue

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have a button that shows a table when clicked on. That's done with bootstrap vue. I made some :hover in the css that highlights it, but i want to keep it highlighted while the table is shown.

the button and table look like this:

```html
<b-btn v-b-toggle.collapse1 class="toggle-table-btn">Cardboard size</b-btn>

 <b-collapse id="collapse1" class="mt-2">

   <b-table striped hover :items="(( table ))"></b-table>

 </b-collapse>
```

and the css

```css
.container .table-box .toggle-table-btn:hover {
    background-color: rgb(63, 63, 63);
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a class on a html object dynamically. Then, you can create a new class that does the same that `hover` does, and apply this new class to your button.

You will need a support variable, to handle the table status `collapsed or not`, I called this support variable as `highlightButton`

In your css, you can "reuse" you hover class declaration for your highlight

```
.container .table-box .toggle-table-btn:hover, .toggle-table-btn.highlight {
    background-color: rgb(63, 63, 63);
    color: white;
}
```

When you click the button, `@click` changes the `highlightButton`'s value, then your class is applied or not.

```
<b-btn v-b-toggle.collapse1 @click.prevent="highlightButton = !highlightButton" :class="['toggle-table-btn', highlightButton ? 'highlight' : '']">Cardboard size</b-btn>

 <b-collapse id="collapse1" class="mt-2">

   <b-table striped hover :items="(( table ))"></b-table>

 </b-collapse>
```

the component data

```
data: function {
    return {
       highlightButton: false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the `v-model` support for the collapse component. This way you can explicitly track whether the table is currently visible or not using a data attribute (`showTable` in my example). You can then use `showTable` to add an extra class to your button dynamically. Use this class to highlight the button while the table is visible.

See this working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/ebbishop/304jws9m